# How to write an SQL query that will return rows that have empty fields?

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query that will output all rows, including the rows that have empty fields in them. But my query only outputs rows with all non-empty fields.

Here's what i mean.

So these are my tables
Table 1: sponsor
[image]

Table 2: contact
[image]

And this is my query:

```
SELECT   s.sponsor_name, s.sub_name, SUM(s.amount), 
         COUNT(s.id), c.contact_name, c.tel
FROM     sponsor as s, contact as c
WHERE (s.id = c.sponsor_id) and (c.is_primary = 1)
GROUP BY sponsor_name, sub_name
```

Here is the output:
[image]

I want the output to show all 3 sponsors like this:
[image]

Comment: MySql or SQL Server?

Comment: @FelixPamittan mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   s.sponsor_name, s.sub_name, SUM(s.amount), 
         COUNT(s.id), c.contact_name, c.tel
FROM     sponsor as s, contact as c
WHERE (s.id = c.sponsor_id) and (c.is_primary = 1)
GROUP BY sponsor_name, sub_name
```

Should then most likely read:

```
SELECT   s.sponsor_name, s.sub_name, SUM(s.amount), 
         COUNT(s.id), c.contact_name, c.tel
FROM     sponsor as s
LEFT JOIN contact as c ON (s.id = c.sponsor_id) and (c.is_primary = 1)
GROUP BY sponsor_name, sub_name
```

The `LEFT JOIN` takes care that leading table data, in this example sponsor is used to the rows to be kept.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're doing an `INNER JOIN`, which drops non-matching rows. You need to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT   
    s.sponsor_name, 
    s.sub_name, 
    SUM(s.amount), 
    COUNT(s.id),
    c.contact_name,
    COALESCE(c.tel, 'N/A') AS tel
FROM  sponsor AS s
LEFT JOIN contact AS c
    ON  s.id = c.sponsor_id
    AND c.is_primary = 1
GROUP BY s.sponsor_name, s.sub_name
```

Additionally, you should be using the explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the old-style syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   s.sponsor_name, s.sub_name, SUM(s.amount), 
         COUNT(s.id), c.contact_name, c.tel
FROM     sponsor as s
Left join contact c on  (s.id = c.sponsor_id) and (c.is_primary = 1)

WHERE (c.sponsor_id is null)
GROUP BY sponsor_name, sub_name
```

Try this. Or if its not ok then try to write sql where checking to identify by `null`